# How i can stop a SKPaymentTransaction?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm writing an app that uses inApp Purchase system but i can't find a way to stop a transaction out the transaction observer methods. I need this behaviour cause in low connectivity situation i wanna give to the users the ability to stop the connection to the apple server. I don't want at the same time that one or more default purchase alert appears maybe 2 or 3 minutes after... So the best solution is to stop completely the payment procedure by an uibutton and an Action. I have tried something like this,but it doesn't work.

---

```
    -(IBAction)ClosePayment{

       for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]transactions])  {
          [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
       }

    }
```

This Action crash the application, i've tried also;

```
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

This don't generate any error but simply don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems impossible to stop SKPaymentTransaction during the "purchasing" state... I have also tried to initialize the related SKPayment object without a TransactionObserver (only for testing purpose...). Without a TransactionObserver the purchase will not work correctly but the first alert of the inapp purchase system will still display to the user. Nothing in documentation support a "stop", so i think that maybe is possible only with some private API.

Comment: If (like me), and you accidentally fired a ton of queue.add(transactions) and wanted to cancel them (instead of tapping cancel on dozens of "purchase" alerts) - the good news is that if you delete the app the alerts will disappear, and if you wait long enough the transactions will slowly time out and you won't have to manually cancel them.